# Handling and retrieving objects

Tags: java, object, linked-list, data-retrieval

I have a singly linkedlist with three nodes.

```
 Rank1[Identity Number: 1, Location at point: 5.4,3.2, Score: 8.2] 
 Rank2[Identity Number: 3, Location at point: 2.2,1.2, Score: 6.0]
 Rank3[Identity Number: 2, Location at point: 1.4,9.2, Score: 7.5]
```

Identity number is integer ,location at point is an object of Point class ,Score is a double.
I'm inserting nodes to the list with Record objects which includes Point object(location at point value).

To have an idea about the variables and the classes:

**Point class:**

```
class Point {
    public double x, y;
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    //Απόσταση με δεδομένο το σημείο p
    public double dist(Point p) {
        return Math.sqrt((this.x-p.x)*(this.x-p.x)+(this.y-p.y)*(this.y-p.y));
    }
```

**Record class:**

```
class Record {
public int id; //Αναγνωριστικό ενός καταστήματος
    public Point location; //Συντεταγμένες του σημείου ενδιαφέροντος
    public double score; //Βαθμολογία του σημείου

    public Record(int id, Point location, double score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
        this.score = score;
    }

    //Επιστρέφει τα στοιχεία που προστέθηκαν για το μαγαζί
    public Record copy() {
        return new Record(
                this.id,
                this.location.copy(),
                this.score
        );
    }
```

**Node class:**

```
public Record poi;
    public Node next;

    public Node(Record poi) {
        this.poi = poi;
    }

    public Record getPoi() {
        return poi;
    }

    public void setPoi(Record poi) {
        this.poi = poi;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return poi.toString();
    }
```

The following class includes the main and nearest method. In main method I'm inserting the values and creating the nodes were defined above. In nearest method I try to calculate the distance between two points of locations and p argument and if the distance is less than maxDist add the node to a new list called nearList.

```
class RankList {
    private Node first;
    private int nodeCount;
    private Record record;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Inserting the nodes to the singly linkedlist
    RankList list1 = new RankList();
    list1.nearest(p,maxDist); //maxDist=8.7 
  }

    public RankList nearest (Point p,double maxDist){
    RankList nearList = new RankList();
    Node current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.print(current);
        if(record.location.dist(p)<maxDist){ //Finding the distance between the added points with p argument
            nearList.insert(record); //Insert the distances shorter than maxDist in a new list.
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println("null");
    return nearList;
}
```

}

I'm trying to retrieve the object Point from each node in order to make a comparison and then add them to a new list. I tried to achieve that with Record object but that seems to not working.

The main problem is that I don't know how to handle the values of a node differently and how to retrieve the ones that I need.

Any suggestions would be really helpful!
Feel free to ask everything about the code.

Comment: What a mess, you present all this code but you don't present your Node class your question is about, the code is not even valid and I have no remote idea what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Is your question "how to get Point instance from Node instance"?

Comment: @Ecto You're right I've added it. I need to extract the Point object of every node in order to make a comparison and add them to a new list.

Comment: @Ecto Yes exactly!

Comment: `node.getPoi().location` ?

Comment: @Ecto I think you're right. The path looks correct but again the new list doesn't get filled.